# 4 Backslash on network path string

Tags: c#, .net, string

If I do this:

```
string path = "\\myServer\myFile.txt"
```

I get a compilation error. So I do this:

```
string path = @"\\myServer\myFile.txt"
```

Altought the output of path in **QUICK WATCH** of Visual Studio is:

```
\\\\myServer\myFile.txt
```

Is there any clean way to avoid the problem of this 4 backslashes?

Comment: "the output of path is" -  _the_ output? What output?

Comment: it was the output in "Quick Watch" of Visual Studio. Sorry. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string path = @"\\"` will not create a string with 4 backslashes. It might look like that in the debugger, but try to `Debug.WriteLine()` it: there's only 2.

Answer (score 3):

> Although the output of path is:
>
> ```
> \\\\myServer\myFile.txt
> ```

No, it's not. The value you might see in the debugger would be

```
\\\\myServer\\myFile.txt
```

- which is just the debugger escaping the value for you.

The value *of the string* has a double backslash at the start, and a single backslash in the middle. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\\myServer\myFile.txt");
```

will print

```
\\myServer\myFile.txt
```

It's important to differentiate the actual content of the string, and some format seen in the debugger.

If you want to express the same string in code *without* using a verbatim string literal (that's the form starting with `@`) you can just escape each backslash:

```
string path = "\\\\myServer\\myFile.txt";
```

Again, the actual *value* there only has a total of three backslashes. For example:

```
string path1 = "\\\\myServer\\myFile.txt";
string path2 = @"\\myServer\myFile.txt";
Console.WriteLine(path1 == path2); // true
```

They're different literals representing the same string content.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have the choise between

```
string test = @"\\myServer\myFile.txt";
```

or

```
string test = "\\\\myServer\\myFile.txt";
```

Both contains `\\myServer\myFile.txt`